# ":D" specifier in LaTeX3

Tags: expl3, latex3

In `expl3.pdf` 3.2.5, I have noticed that the `:D` specifier means "DO NOT USE" and "programmers outside the kernel team should not use these functions". But I also find that these functions are appeared in some packages written in LaTeX3.

So can anybody tell me that whether I can use them after all?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077)

Comment: Could you please show some examples where you found the D specifier in packages?

Comment: @TeXnician Although I try to avoid them I sometimes use those primitives (the obvious being `\tex_endinput:D` for example , but also `\tex_penalty:D` and probably others…)

Comment: @JosephWright I usually end all code files with `\endinput` and include a change history of the file after it…

Comment: @clemens You do not like dtx?

Comment: Clearly they should have gone for `:(`.

Comment: @clemens `\endinput` is not experimentally supported _via_ `\file_input_stop:` (release _today_ so either grab from GitHub or wait for CTAN ...)

Answer (score 12):

The `:D` specifier is used exclusively for primitives (all primitives are initial `\<engine>_<name>:D`), and ideas none should appear outside of the core  team code. (Broadly that means outside of `l3kernel` but there are some special cases where we expect `:D` names to be used in limited places in other kernel-level code.)

However, it's clear that there are areas that the team have not yet covered in `expl3` or where interaction with LaTeX2e requires direct access to primitives. For *interim* work on modules where there are currently no official interfaces, the team recommend that code addressing such cases be formulated as

```
\cs_new_eq:NN \__module_name:w \engine_name:D % Probably :w ...
```

and the latter name is used in such places: this leaves only a single line to be adjusted as the team address such issues. It is also likely to be worth raising these with the team either directly on or LaTeX-L. For example, I am recently added support for `\pdffilesize` and similar as experimental additions to `l3file` as a result of such requests.

For working with LaTeX2e, where we might expect the code never to 'move on', one would usual stick to the 'classical' name.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that at one point everything was renamed as `:D` then renamed again so even the kernel didn't use those names directly. We've somewhat modified that position as it can hinder rather than aid clarity: at the lowest level one does need to know that a primitive is in use.

Comment: For example, I need to use `\par` in my code. So the way is `\cs_new_eq:NN \_xxx_par: \tex_par:D`, right?

Comment: @Stone-Zeng `\par` is a tricky one as it interacts with the galley (both in LaTeX2e and `expl3`),and as the name is special (TeX inserts the token `\par` not the `\par` primitive when for example dealing with a blank line). Normally I'd say you just want `\par` rather than the primitive, though without a use case it's a bit tricky. (I'm currently re-reading some `l3galley` code, and that requires that only our code messes with 'raw' `\tex_par:D` tokens.  OK, it's not really used so not an issue ...).

Comment: @Stone-Zeng To be clear, if you want the `\par` primitive then 'yes, that's the correct approach at present'.

Comment: And how about \fill, \hfil, \hfill etc.?

Comment: @Stone-Zeng They all fall within the 'typesetting stuff' area that we've not addressed ...